# partially refund not working proper

Tags: magento2, invoice, creditmemo

i have try to refund invoice in following code 

`$invoice = $this->_invoiceService
                ->prepareInvoice($order_refund,$itemsArray);
$invoice  ->setRequestedCaptureCase 
                           (\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Invoice::CAPTURE_ONLINE);
$count=count($orderDetail->getAllItems());
$totalShipping=$orderDetail->getShippingAmount();
$ship=($totalShipping/$count);
$invoice->setShippingAmount($ship);
$invoice->register();
$invoice->save();
$creditmemoItem = $this->itemCreationFactory->create();
$creditmemoItem->setQty(1)->setOrderItemId($items_Id);
$itemIdsToRefund[] = $creditmemoItem;
$this->invoiceRefunder->execute($invoice->getId(),$itemIdsToRefund,true);`

invoice automatically refund full amount of shipping
when an i have already changed its shipping amount.

what is wrong with this?